# Bootstrap columns not stacking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

Please I'm using bootstrap 4 beta to build a website, the columns don't stack on mobile devices, however they do when I use Google Chrome to resize the window. 
Even in chrome responsive mode, they don't stack also
Any help please?

```
  <!--main-->
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <section class="news-items">
                    <h1>AfEI News</h1>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col-lg-3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col-lg-3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col-lg-3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 col-lg-3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 aside-col" id="coming-up">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 aside-col" id="opportunities">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 columns not stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025961/bootstrap-3-columns-not-stacking)

Answer (score 1):

If it works properly when you resize the window but not on a mobile device, you are probably missing this in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to view it on an actual mobile device? I've noticed using chrome the responsive elements and dev options don't actually simulate a mobile device. Also, you do not need to use `col-md-12` just use `col` and it will auto fit.

You should also use the current full release of bs4, here is the documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Answers should not start with a question. Please read on SO's https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I understand however it wouldn't allow me to write a comment. @Matt

Comment: @Matt Please take the downvote off. There is nothing on that page that says an answer can't start with a question.

Answer (score -1):

it is due to you are placing all together like

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
 </div>
```

So in this can it will tough for browser to align it proper as it wont know where to place the third one as space is filled.

So what you need to do is tell the browser to place it in next row by using the bootstrap class itself

```html
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"  >
test
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
      test
     </div>
</div>
 <div class="row" >    
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
     test
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
      test
     </div>
   </div>
```

Now you will get it proper.

Comment: There is no reason more than 12 units can't be used in a single row